# SSIS Package Deployment Failure using SSDT

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, ssis-2012, ssdt

SSIS fails almost immediately on the final "Deploying project" step of the Deployment Wizard (Package Deployment Model), using Visual Studio 2010 (SSDT) connecting to a SQL 2012 Server:

```
Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '10028'.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27203)
```

The report XML contains few clues to the issue, however the "0x80131904" could indicate a possibly network library issue.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '10026'. &#xD;
                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
...
 Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder.DeployProject(String projectName, Byte[] projectStream)
...    
Error Number:27203,State:1,Class:16
```

The `Operation_Messages` view returns no data for that ID.

The Integration Services' Catalog `All Operations` report simply reports a Failed/Deploy Project.

Interestingly, the package deploys successfully if I run the Wizard via the SQL Server Management Studio (right-click on the `Projects` tab for the project and choose `Deploy Project` and browse/import the `ispac` file). Note that I'm running SSMS remotely as well as VS2010/SSDT, so I'm not sure why only VS2010 is failing.

I also tried adjusting the `Server-wide Default Logging Level` to `Verbose` but this didn't seem to provide any additional info.

Any thoughts on why SSDT is failing to deploy the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this error (and pulling my hair out) -- even though I didn't have any rows in the operation_message view, there was a row in [catalog].[operations].  I noticed server_name was the old name of the machine.  For the most recent successful deployment in [catalog].[operations], the server_name was the current name of the machine.

I also noticed both SELECT @@SERVERNAME and SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME') were both returning the machine's old name.  (Usually @@SERVERNAME would have the stale name but SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME') would have the current name).

So I ran

```
exec sp_dropserver 'old_name';
GO
exec sp_addserver 'current_name';
GO
```

and restarted the SQL service, and then the deploy worked.